# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable

Tags: android

I was following the Google provided example of how to use AnimationDrawable with an ImageView. You can find it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html

```
 image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.run_animation);

        frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) image.getDrawable();
        frameAnimation.start();
```

drawable file run_animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/iv1"
        android:duration="500" />

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/iv2"
        android:duration="500" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/iv3"
        android:duration="500" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/iv4"
        android:duration="500" />

</animation-list>
```

Upon execution i am receciving this error on logcat

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable
```

please help me.

Comment: You can see similar thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951712/android-animationdrawable-cast-error). As @TheOneX said in that thread try getDrawable() rather than getBackground()

Comment: It is not working

Comment: Did u try with getDrawable() than image.getBackground()?

Comment: I tried that code & but it is not working for me

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable

Comment: I am receiving that error after changing to getDrawable

Comment: Can u post ur updated code?

Comment: Please share the code of R.drawable.run_animation.

Comment: i have added the updated code.

Comment: I'm not sure, the first line just try with this: image.setImageDrawable(getResource().getDrawable(R.drawable.run_animation);

Comment: i tried your code but i am receiving this error at frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) image.getDrawable();

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable

Comment: Just for clarification you have this run_animation.xml file in drawable folder right?

Comment: Can u try this one too: image.setBackgroundDrawable(getResource().getDrawable(R.drawable.‌​run_animation));
frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) image.getBackground();